# Ember.js 1.13: The right way to observe a passed-in attribute of component?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components, ember-observable

I'm trying to upgrade my project to Ember 1.13, and I'm a bit confused about the behavior of new **attrs** of **component**, especially when I have to observe them.

For example, my test component observes **bar** which is a parameter passed from outside. I know in Ember's new Glimmer engine, the component rerenders once any of its attribute changes. What I can't figure out is that the observer will also be fired at that time if I observe **attrs.bar** (I didn't modify **bar**!). But if I observe **bar** itself then it'll be fine.

The sample code:

HTMLBar:

```
 {{test-cpnt foo=foo bar=bar}}
 <input type="button" {{action 'tap'}} value="tap"/>
```

Controller:

```
 foo: 1,
 bar: 100,
 actions: {
   tap: function(){
     this.set('foo', this.get('foo')+1);
   }
 }
```

Component:

```
App.TestCpntComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  barObv1: Ember.observer('bar', function(){
    console.log('bar observer is fired!');
  }),

  barObv2: Ember.observer('attrs.bar', function(){ 
    console.log('attrs.bar observer is fired!');
  }),
});
```

By tapping the button to change **foo**'s value, we will trigger **barObv2** as well.
I've created a jsbin for demo:
https://jsbin.com/qiwivu/2/edit?js,console,output

Does anyone know why the observer got triggered?

Comment: your jsbin seems to not work for me but I porting over to twiddle to get a better understanding of your question:
https://ember-twiddle.com/acb8cbf30c7dbbd0a4b2

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have to use observers since you are in Ember 1.13, you can make use of `didUpdateAttrs` which is triggered whenever an attribute is updated.

```
Ember.Component.extend({
....
 didUpdateAttrs({oldAttrs, newAttrs}) {
   let oldBar = get(oldAttrs, 'bar.value');
   let newBar = get(newAttrs, 'bar.value');

   if (oldBar !== new Bar) {
      // your logic here
   }
 }
....
});
```

If you intend to use observer, you can observe for the changes like below

```
barDidChange: Ember.observer('bar', function(){ 
 console.log('bar observer is fired!');
});
```

Listening for `attrs.bar` will not work properly, whenever an attribute is updated (including init), attrs are mutated every time which causes the observers to trigger, for more refer [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.13.13/packages/ember-metal-views/lib/renderer.js#L170-L175). `attrs` are supposed to be used with `angle-bracket components`. Here is a nice [article](https://locks.svbtle.com/to-attrs-or-not-to-attrs) why we should not use attrs for curly components.